# Auto Populate Fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a **product** object where there are **price** field in it. **Product** has a **lookup** to product and if I select the product I need to generate price field automatically in text box. And there is another field named **Quantity** where I want to  add a formula field by multiplying **price* quantity** to update price in second step and I want to add a total field I will update there. How can I autopopulate fields based on product selected and update price field.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### Option 1

Use a formula field to pull in the looked up to product's price * the entered quantity to display the total price. This would look something like this:

Field type = Formula (currency) | Name = Total Price

```
Product.Quantity__c * Product__r.Price__c
```

### Option 2

Alternatively if you need the ability to override the Price before the total is calculated you will want to do this:

Create a Currency field called Price and write a workflow rule to fire everytime the record is created/edited and set the criteria using a formula

```
OR(IsChanged(Product__c), ISNUll(Price__c)
```

Set the rule to be a field update | `update the Price__c` field to `Product__r.Price__c`

then create the total price formula

Field type = Formula (currency) | Name = Total Price

```
Product.Quantity__c * Product.Price__c
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you work through the warehouse tutorials found in the [Force.com Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/forcecom_workbook.pdf). It should provide you with all the learning tools and references needed to figure out how to do what you're asking.